# Change color of an element from colors.xml

Tags: java, android

I tried using `R.color` but it doesn't show up custom colors I've created.

To be specific.
I want to be able to access specified in colors.xml in a custom view I'm creating

```
int indicator_color=getResources().getColor(R.color.my_magic_color);
```

This color is stored in colors.xml

```
<resources>
 <item name="my_magic_color" type="color">#FF33B5E5</item>
</resources>
```

Comment: Have you checked your import of `R`? You should import `com.yourproject.app.R` instead of `android.R`. Alternatively, you can access the newly created color fully qualified, e.g. `com.yourproject.app.R.color.my_magic_color`.

Comment: That was it. Stupid error. Post as answer and I'll mark it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As posted as a comment above:

To have access to custom defined colors you have to import the generated `R` class of your project, instead of `android.R`.

So in the import area of your class, replace

```
import android.R;
```

with

```
import your.project.app.R;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a color tag in you XML instead of an item tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="my_magic_color">#FF33B5E5</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: Just for the record. You can do it both ways